# How can I get Gurobi status codes in AMPL?

Tags: gurobi, ampl

I would like to know how can I get the Gurobi Status Code - optimum found, infeasible etc. (the possible results are listed in http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/ampl-gurobi/results.html) from AMPL after running the optimization.

Here is my `.run` code

```
model model.md;
data input.dat;
option solver gurobi;
option gurobi_options 'logfile=log.txt timelim=60 writeprob=model.lp 
resultfile=sol.sol';
problem oampl: fo, variables, constraints;
solve oampl;
```

And `model.md` have the model with the objective function (fo), variables and constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Based on *Solver statuses of objectives and problems* in [section 14.2 of the AMPL book](http://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/17-solvers.pdf), try:

```
ampl: display solve_exitcode;
solve_exitcode = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understood well, the solve_exitcode shows only if the solver invocation was successful or not. But, actually, I would like to have codes indicating if the solution was an optimal, suboptimal, unbounded etc.

Comment: Exit codes include infeasible, unbounded, ...: http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/ampl-gurobi/results.html